# Filebeat prevents python rotating log from rotating files in windows os

Tags: python, windows, logging, filebeat

Environment:
win 10
python 2.7
Filebeat 5.1.1

My application writes logs with Rotating log handler. When I start Filebeat I start getting the following exceptions from logging lib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “C:\Anaconda2\Lib\logging\handlers.py”, line 77, in emit
   self.doRollover()
File “C:\Anaconda2\Lib\logging\handlers.py”, line 142, in 
doRollover
   os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already 
exists
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Hard to guess without a [mcve]. Could you setup a minimal logging system with a very short max bytes value to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my resolution.

In Filebeat [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#close-renamed) - written if you have problems with rotating logs in windows you should use:
close_renamed: true
close_removed: true

I tried it but it didn't work due to the wrong indentation in config.
fixed it and now I don't have any issue.